# How to extract a char from a string AT&T Assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, att

I'm currently doing I/O in AT&T but I've been stuck for quite a decent time with a silly problem so I decided to turn to Stack Overflow.

I want to separate one part of the string which is input from the user in a function before the handling function, storing it in $in:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movq    $in, %rdi                     
movq    $5,%rsi
movq    stdin, %rdx
call    fgets
```

In the function where I'm stuck I'm trying to extract one char from the string to compare it if it's an ascii number, special sign etc. but the problem for the moment is the "extracting" part.

I have tried everything I can think of, pushing it, I have a feeling that it would be as easy as to add/subtract to the address but I can't get the syntax into my head..

Here is the latest try:

```
movq    $in,    %r10
movb    (%r10), %al
movb    %al,    (%rdx)
```

but I can't access it through gdb:

```
(gdb) x/12cb $al
0x31:   Cannot access memory at address 0x31
```

Grateful for any response!

Comment: Using the `x` command on `$al` makes no sense. `x` takes an address as an argument. `$al` is too small to contain an address. It looks like you're trying to view a string (`12cb`) by passing the value of a register that contains the first byte of the string. That can't work! The value in the register may have come from the first byte of the string buffer, but it's an independent copy now, of just that one byte, with no relation to the rest of the string. Try `x/12cb in` to view the buffer.

Comment: IIRC the `x` debugger command is for examining memory. You're trying to print a register, not memory. The error message indicates the byte you're interested in is simply 0x31 (which is not a valid memory address).

Comment: Ah I see I mistook the address for the register.  The buffer is correct, containing the input but then I want to return one char from the string and I don't know how to do it/control the char if not like that with gdb. Any pointers?

Comment: It's unclear what you want.

Comment: I want to go through the characters of the string and handle the input depending on what char (ASCII) the user entered: + - or integer 1-99 or space.  To do this I have multiple functions and this function is supposed to return a character similar to a getint() function. To do this I tried to extract one char from the string while monitoring the value in gdb. It proved that I couldn't monitor the value using the method I used so I'm wondering how I could do it or how I could perform what I described earlier.

Comment: `p $al` for example.